# Clearing cache breaks routing symfony

Tags: php, symfony, caching

Is this supposed to happen? Let me explain.

I have a pretty basic symfony project already deployed on a server **in prod environment** with a few basic objects created with

```
generate:doctrine:entity.
```

I used those entities to create views with the

```
doctrine:generate:crud
```

command. After a bit of tinkering to set everything right for my project it <s>all (still) worked perfectly</s> (edit: I lied, I just thought it did). I put a few test objects in and uploaded to database. That worked too. Then I cleared the prod cache, and tried to add another object. That works too, the entry gets put in my database. The old (test) entries still exist and their pages I can navigate to. However, all pages relating to that new entry, or any new entries created after the cache clear, give 404 errors.

Is this supposed to happen and should I clear the database first next time, or did something break?

---

Edit: well, now I'm lost. I had made an error with my optional parameter names in my controllers. I hadn't given them the same name as the parameter slugs, so the behaviour for which entities got pulled from the database was really wonky. Still don't understand why this didn't become apparent until I cleared my cache, but fixing the names fixed my issue too, it doesn't happen anymore.

I'm pretty new to SO, should I delete the question? It seems useless now.

Comment: It is hard to understand your problem. Are you in `prod` or `dev` environnement? (do you use `app_dev.php`)? what do you have in logs?

Comment: As stated by SO, it's better to close the question if the question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error (simple coding mistakes). While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers (like in your case). PS: This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.

Comment: @Thibauld-nuyten Yes it is better